# Is Rhin a useful party member?

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

I know that "Torment: Tides of the Numenara" is a story focused game and running with a child in your group is definitely an interesting experience, but besides the unique flavour, to say it blunt: is there any use for the runaway "Child who talks to gods"?

She has no combat stats, and so far I haven't seen anything else that she could do, except... well, being your adopted child.

Does she eventually grow into an useful party member? Or maybe there is a place where you can leave her safely? And no, I'm not talking about the slaver who is looking for her.

EDIT: I've just found [this interesting guide](https://steamcommunity.com/app/272270/discussions/0/350533172694212919/): It seems that she can be trained into being quite useful runner/stealth specialist she can also work wonders with cyphers, because she can use any cypher twice in a row.

Comment: Also keep in mind, that combat rarely is mandatory. I keep her in my party, just to find what is actually going with her, I don't care, that in combat she can do nothing but use cyphers. But, as you said, she is good at hiding and that's also a good way to solve combat encounters.

Answer (score 3):

If you have her with you in the bloom

> You can send her to her home, she then will join you as an adult in the end game, much more powerful

Answer (score 2):

I've played a bit more and she certainly becomes a decent combatant once you reach tier 2.

On tier 2, she gets access to the innervate esotery, combine that with her skill level in healing and she becomes a very good healer.

Also, if you give her speed based light ranged weapon and invest edge and stat pool into speed she can do some decent damage at range. Due to her extremely high evasion she also is not as squishy as she looks.